# alert not displaying when using button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, alert

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/dmsrY/8/)'s the fiddle.

I'm trying to make it so when you click the button it alerts `'You tried to search...` ...whatever you typed...`!'`, but the button doesn't alert the message.

I've already tried using:

```
var a = document.getElementById('input').value;
    alert("You tried to search " + a + "!");
```

and it still doesn't alert the message, please answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is inaccessible outside of it's closure. It should be

```
window.search = function() {
    var a = document.getElementById('input').value;
    alert("You tried to search " + a + "!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you code will run as soon as this page is loading,you can optimize your code like this [use jquery]:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#search').onclick(function() {
          var a = document.getElementById('input').value;
          alert("You tried to search " + a + "!");
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using jQuery, you should bind click event using jQuery, it will be better, http://jsfiddle.net/dmsrY/13/

remove onclick

```
<button id="clickme" type="button" title="Search" value="Search">Search</button>
```

and you can call the `search()` in same scope

```
$('#clickme').click(function () {
    search( $('#input').val() );
});

// make search function more flexible
function search(s) {
    alert(s);
}
```

if you want to access `search()` everywhere

```
// create jQuery plugin function
$.search = function (s) {
    alert(s);
}

// now you can call search like this
$.search('search string');
```